# How to send Array of integer values to Rails 3 destroy Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Rails Application that is trying to destroy Multiple entries from database.I have tried like ,

```
http://localhost:3000/users?ïds[]=1&ids[]=2
```

In my controller

```
def destroy

  ids = params[:ids]
  User.where(:id => ids).destroy_all

end
```

I am getting an error like this,

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/users"):

It is showing a routing error..
How to fix this...
Thanks in advance..

Comment: How about you fix your `routes` file first ? and if you don't know what to fix there, show its content. You could also check you do have the route with `rake routes CONTROLLER=users`

Comment: i have set rosources :users in my route file .....i have also checked rake routes..it shows the route users/:id{.:format}  DELETE

Comment: by default rails accept ':id' in delete route......but i read it also accepts integer array of ids.....see the link http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001800

Comment: i can delete in default way,it works fine....http://localhost:3000/users/1

Answer (score 2):

The `delete users/:id{.:format} => destroy` route is for member, i.e. only one item.

You need to create a collection route and a customized action for this.

```
#routes.rb
resources :users, :collection => {:delete_all => :delete}

#users_controller.rb
def delete_all
  ids = get_ids_from_params
  User.delete_all(["id in (?)", ids])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is to add a separate route. If you want to reuse the destroy action you can use this approach(ids must be integer based)

**View**

To destroy single user

```
link_to(user_path(id), :method => :delete) #  user/1
```

To destroy multiple users

```
link_to(user_path(ids.join("-")), :method => :delete) #  user/1-2-3
```

**Controller**

```
def destroy
  ids = params[:id].split("-")
  User.where(:id => ids).destroy_all
end
```

Now your destroy action will work with single/multiple ids.

Comment: It is working good ,but is this the right method...because i need to send a set of id seperated by ',' . Is it possible to send array of integers.

Comment: The URL returned by Rails is a string. So nothing is stopping you from passing a URL complaint string as id. It is up-to your controller action to determine what to do with the id. The code to convert array to `-` separated string is trivial. On the other hand, you might be better off creating an entirely new action to handle the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The link you gave doesn't say you can pass an array to the default DELETE route. It only says that you can call `.delete_all` on a relation or array of ActiveRecord objects.

Now, the reason this doesn't work is that you have just the default routes provided by `resources :user`. That includes a DELETE route, to be sure. It's `DELETE /users/:id`. I have no idea if you could pass an array as `:id`, but you certainly can't pass anything as `:ids`, as you attempt to do - that won't match the route.

If you really do need an action that deletes multiple records by id, you should probably add a custom route to in your routes file. I think the correct form for the request would be along the lines of `users/destroy_all?ids[]=1&ids[]=2`, as documented [here](http://www.spacevatican.org/2008/7/18/parametrised-to-the-max/), and the route would probably look something like this:

```
resources :users do
  delete '/users/destroy_all/:ids' => 'users#destroy_all'
end
```

I haven't actually tried this, it may not work.